# What are the differences between the SpaceX Merlin 1D and 1D+ engines?

Tags: spacex, engines, merlin-1d

I am trying to model the Merlin 1D+ using inventor. I was wondering what the major differences between the Merlin 1D and 1D+ were. I find when I search trying to find a 1D+ engine all I come across is 1D.

Also, I know the basic parts of a rocket engine and I know the Merlin is a gas generator cycle. However, I am wondering if the heat exchanger on the nozzle is for heating the helium and cooling the nozzle or heating the LOX while still cooling the nozzle?

Comment: It would not be helium in any case.

Comment: Oh I thought that SpaceX uses the liquid helium from the COPVs and heats it over the nozzle to pressurize the tanks.

Comment: That is possible, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

SpaceX is behaving very unlike traditional aerospace companies by iterating their design on a regular basis. While they carved out major updates as Merlin 1A, 1B, 1C, and 1D, it has been a constant that they tweak within versions quite regularly.

It is unclear if there is a defined product Merlin 1D+ as opposed to the Full Thrust Merlin 1D.